# How to make a loop-generated table depending on the outcome of a calculation?

Tags: tables, exam, foreach, loops, pgfmathparse

As a Dutch teacher my grading scale goes from 1,0 to 10,0. The calculation of the grade depends on three variables: the N-term; the score of the student; the total number of points for the exam.

I would like my exams to automatically generates a grading table such that it consists of four seperated tables where each table contains a specific parts of the grading scale: [1,0;3,2] and [3,3;5,4] and [5,5;7,7] and [7,8;10,0].

With N-term=1,0 and a total score (including zero points) divisible by four it'll lead to four tables of same lenght. In many other cases not. See example below.

This is an example for a N-term of 0,0 and a total number of 47 points:

[image]

So far, I've got a code that does most of the trick. The problem however is that the lengt of each seperated table is manually determined in the code. I would really like that this would also go automatically.

A former classmate wrote the code; for most parts I'm not sure how it works.

The making of the table works with an foreach loop. The `\i` that is used refers to the points of the candidate, where the ending of the table depends on the grade corresponding to a certain number of points.

So maybe a `\foreach \i in {0,...,\GetNumPoints} \while 1,0 =< \NormFormule =< 3.2` or someting like that works better. But I've no idea how it can be done.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

%-----------------------------------------
% The Nterm determines which grade correspends to which grade; this is normally a number between 0,0 and 2,0
%-----------------------------------------
\newcommand{\Nterm}{1.0}

%-----------------------------------------
% This is some prework that needs to be done
%-----------------------------------------
\makeatletter
   \providecommand{\exam@numpoints}{1}%
   \newcommand{\GetNumPoints}{\exam@numpoints}%
    \newcommand*{\@MyTempTableTokens}{}%
    \newtoks\@tabtoks
    %%% assignments to \@tabtoks must be global, because they are done in \foreach
    \newcommand\AddTableTokens[1]{\global\@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks#1}}
    \newcommand\eAddTableTokens[1]{% 
        \protected@edef\@MyTempTableTokens{#1}%
        \expandafter\AddTableTokens\expandafter{\@MyTempTableTokens}}
    %%% variable should always be operated on either always locally or always globally
    \newcommand*\ResetTableTokens{\global\@tabtoks{}}
    \newcommand*\PrintTableTokens{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\NormFormule}[1]{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        \ifdim \Nterm pt < 1 pt
            max(
                9 * ( #1 / \GetNumPoints ) + \Nterm ,
                1 + ( #1 * ( 9 / \GetNumPoints ) * 0.5 ),
                10 - ( \GetNumPoints - #1 ) * ( 9 / \GetNumPoints ) * 2
            )
        \else
            min(
                9 * ( #1 / \GetNumPoints ) + \Nterm ,
                1 + ( #1 * ( 9 / \GetNumPoints ) * 2 ),
                10 - ( \GetNumPoints - #1 ) * ( 9 / \GetNumPoints ) * 0.5
            )       
        \fi
    }
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=1, fixed zerofill, use comma]{\pgfmathresult}}


%-----------------------------------------
% This is the command for making the table; which works fine. Except for needing to manually define the length of the specific tables
%-----------------------------------------
\newcommand{\maketable}{\bigskip
\Huge Grading Table\bigskip\\\normalsize
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {0,...,14}   %THIS IS WHERE I GOT STUCK!
    {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}{}                 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(1{,}0-3{,}2)$\\       
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}  
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {15,...,29} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(3{,}3-5{,}4)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}          
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {30,...,44} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(5{,}5-7{,}7)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}      
    \ResetTableTokens
    \foreach \i in {45,...,\GetNumPoints} {\eAddTableTokens{\i & \noexpand\NormFormule{\i} \\}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering$(7{,}8-10{,}0)$\\
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                \hline
                \textbf{score}&\textbf{grade}\\\hline\centering
                \PrintTableTokens
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
}


%-----------------------------------------
% And here the actual exam begins
%-----------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question[60]
    The content of this question is irrelevant.
\end{questions}

\maketable

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the N term stand for? How would it affect the output?

Comment: It also don't quite get how you want the output to look like. What do you mean with "specific part" that should be represented in each table part? Do you want the tables to have the same height (entries spread evenly)? Or do you want to include items up to a certain number in the first, second, ... table part?

Comment: The Nterm is used to get a certain avarage grade. When the results are known the Nterm is determined. The standard formule is score/total*9+1. So the standard Nterm is 1,0 and when the test was hard the Nterm is higher, say 1,5. But we want the zero points always to have the grade 1,0 and the full points a grade 10. Therefore, there are boundaries. A nice graphic is shown here https://natuurkundeuitgelegd.nl/n-term-berekening.php 
The \pgfmathparse{} parts shows the code. But I think only the value of \NormFormule is relevant. How it gets to that value is irrelevant.

Comment: I want four tables. The first one with all the scores corresponding with the grades from 1,0 to 3,2; the second one from 3,3 to 5,4; the third one from 5,5 tot 7,7; the last one from 7,8 to 10,0. With N-term=1,0 and a total score (including zero points) divisible by four it'll lead to four tables of same lenght. In many other cases not. See example I posted.

Comment: So, I think the least invasive change to your code would be to somehow calculate the number of rows for each table part before you do the `\foreach` loop that creates this table. You can then use `\foreach \i in {0,...,\calculatednumber}`. However, it feels that you would do the same calculations twice somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the complete code with expl3 syntax, because I think this is easier to maintain in the long run. Also, things became a bit easier this way. I used the `siunitx` package to format the numbers.

I think that this code what you want: It outputs four columns with the required grading scales. The length of the columns differs depending on the number of points you can get.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
% use siunitx to format numbers
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 1,
    output-decimal-marker = {,}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% variable that stores the amount of exam points
\fp_new:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp { 1.0 }

% variable that stores the nterm
\fp_new:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp { 1.0 }
% command to change the nterm
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetPointsNterm}{ m }{
    \fp_gset:Nn \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp { #1 }
}

\makeatletter
% internal command to retrieve the current amount of exam points
% set by the exam class
\cs_new:Npn \kenadams_exampoints_update: {
    \cs_if_exist:cT { exam@numpoints } {
        \fp_gset:Nn \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp { \exam@numpoints }
    }
}
\makeatother

% internal command to calculate a score from a given point value
% the logic is taken over from the original code
\cs_new:Npn \kenadams_exampoints_calculatescore:n #1 {
    \fp_eval:n {
        round( \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp < 1 ? 
            max(
                9 * ( #1 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) + \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp ,
                1 + ( #1 * ( 9 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) * 0.5 ),
                10 - ( \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp - #1 ) * ( 9 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) * 2
            )
        : 
            min(
                9 * ( #1 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) + \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp ,
                1 + ( #1 * ( 9 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) * 2 ),
                10 - ( \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp - #1 ) * ( 9 / \g_kenadams_exampoints_exampoints_fp ) * 0.5
            ) 
        , 1 , 1 )
    }
}

% internal variable (counter) that stores the current table row 
\int_new:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int
% internal command to create a part of the set of tables
\cs_new:Npn \kenadams_exampoints_tablepart:nnn #1 #2 {
    % clearing temporary sequence variable
    \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq 
    % stepwise increase table row number as long as 
    % the calculated score from this value is less than #2
    \fp_do_until:nNnn { \kenadams_exampoints_calculatescore:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int } } > { #2 } {
        % add formatted table row to sequence variable
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_seq { 
            \int_use:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int & 
            \num { \kenadams_exampoints_calculatescore:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int } } 
        }
        \int_gincr:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int
    }
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth} \centering (\num{#1}--\num{#2}) \\       
        \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
            \hline
            \textbf{score} & \textbf{grade} \\ \hline
            % insert the values stored in the sequence variable
            % and add \\ after each item
            \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}

% command to print the grading table
\NewDocumentCommand{\MakePointsTable}{ }{
    % retrieve current amount of exam points
    \kenadams_exampoints_update:
    % reset table row counter
    \int_gzero:N \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int

    \bigskip
    \Huge Grading ~ Table 
    \bigskip \par
    \normalsize
    
    % typeset the four parts of the grading table
    \kenadams_exampoints_tablepart:nnn { 1.0 } { 3.2 }
    \kenadams_exampoints_tablepart:nnn { 3.3 } { 5.4 } 
    \kenadams_exampoints_tablepart:nnn { 5.5 } { 7.7 }
    \kenadams_exampoints_tablepart:nnn { 7.8 } { 10.0 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

%-----------------------------------------
% The Nterm determines which grade correspends to which grade; this is normally a number between 0,0 and 2,0
%-----------------------------------------
\SetPointsNterm{1.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question[60]
    The content of this question is irrelevant.
\end{questions}

\MakePointsTable

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For `\question[47]` you would get:

[image]

---

For `\question[47]` and `\SetPointsNterm{0.0}` you would get:

[image]

Comment: Nitpicking, but not too much: variables should be prefixed by `l_` if local and `g_` if global.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I know this, but I forgot it. But then, it is not always clear to me whether things are global or not, but I guess, all variables should be set globally here.

Comment: That looks great after a first quick look. I'll give it a moor deep look soon and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @KenAdams The code does more or less what the original code does. I added comments to it to explain what the code does. The most relevant change is `\fp_do_until:nNnn { \kenadams_exampoints_calculatescore:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int } } > { #2 } { ...` which essentially increases the score by 1 and creates a table row as long as the grade calculated from this score is below a certain value (e.g. 3.2).

Comment: Almost lovely! It seems to almost work perfect in my more complex document :-)

I put the \sisetup within the specific part of the code, because in my exams I use another setup. This seems to work.

Two questions:
1) How can I print the value of \SetPointsNterm{0.0} in my document? Something like: The N-term of this exam is \PointsNterm.
2) There seems to be a problem with the rounding. For example a Nterm of 1.0 and a total score of 57 gives a grade of 3,2 for 14 points. The value is 3,25 en this should be 3,3. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: @KenAdams Create a new command (somewhere between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`): `\NewDocumentCommand{\PointsNterm}{ }{ \num{ \fp_eval:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp } } }`.

Comment: @KenAdams Are you sure about the value? You can change the rounding-precision in the `\sisetup` to `round-precision = 3` and also change the second value of the `round()` function to `3` (it is `1` in the code above). The result for 14 is 3,211 (albeit being in the second column, why is that?).

Comment: The printing works. Thanks. As regards the rounding issue: I meant a total of 56 in stead of 57. (There's a difference of two regarding the lengt of the first to tables. I think that's never possible for a N-term 1,0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151385/discussion-between-kenadams-and-jasper-habicht).

Comment: @KenAdams There was in fact an issue with the `round` function of which I got the meaning of the third parameter wrong. I fixed this. Now, as you can see, the length difference between the first two tables for 60 questions and N = 1 is not 2 any more.

Comment: Wow, you're great. One last question: why does ```\NewDocumentCommand{\PointsNterm}{ }{ \num[round-precision=1]{ \fp_eval:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_nterm_fp } } }``` not work? Same for ```\num[round-precision=1] { \kenadams_exampoints_calculatescore:n { \g_kenadams_exampoints_tablerow_int } }```.  Seems to me that is easiest way to keep the setup I used before for the rest of the document.

Comment: @KenAdams What does not work with this? You can only use underscores between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. So the best idea is to create some user command (without underscore) in the preamble.

Comment: I see. That works fine. Thanks a lót!